# Multi Tenancy in a SAAS REST API Authentication

Tags: api, rest, authentication, multi-tenant, saas

I'm currently developing a  API to commercialized in a B2B SAAS fashion.
The goal is to authenticate the worker of the company. We have an SDK that should be able to do that. There is the possibility to force each user to set credentials specific for our service, but that will hurt integration with companies applications.

The idea would be to have some kind of authentication (client independent) that make it easier to authenticate users.

The question is: There is a easy way to create an automatic process that does not depend on the client type of authentication methods, for this type of task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OAuth would be my suggestion. Trust the token generated to authenticate the API as same as the web.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/)? It specifically supports multi-tenant scenarios.

Tenants can use [Azure AD Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) to sync their on-premise directory to the cloud. Clients can use [ADAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) to acquire a token which your service trusts. The issued token contains a `tenant-id` claim indicating via which tenant the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to MvdD answer, in Azure AD support three ways to sign in:

> Federated Single Sign-On enables applications to redirect to Azure AD
>   for user authentication instead of prompting for its own password.
>   This is supported for applications that support protocols such as SAML
>   2.0, WS-Federation, or OpenID Connect, and is the richest mode of single sign-on.
>
> Password-based Single Sign-On enables secure application password
>   storage and replay using a web browser extension or mobile app. This
>   leverages the existing sign-in process provided by the application,
>   but enables an administrator to manage the passwords and does not
>   require the user to know the password.
>
> Existing Single Sign-On enables Azure AD to leverage any existing
>   single sign-on that has been set up for the application, but enables
>   these applications to be linked to the Office 365 or Azure AD access
>   panel portals, and also enables additional reporting in Azure AD when
>   the applications are launched there.